# UIActivityViewController crash in Test Flight but not when built from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, crash, uiactivityviewcontroller

I encounter a strange issue here.

I integrated a **UIActivityViewController** in my app (handeling iPhone's and iPad's). Everything works just fine when I build the app from Xcode but it crashes when I distribute it on Test Flight.

---

**Here is the code I use to integrate it :**

```
let textToShare = NSLocalizedString("SHARE_APP_TEXT", comment: "text to share")

    if let myWebsite = NSURL(string: NSLocalizedString("SHARE_APP_LINK", comment: "link to share"))
    {
        let objectsToShare = [textToShare, myWebsite]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList]

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone) {
            self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            var popup:UIPopoverController = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: activityVC)
            popup.presentPopoverFromRect(CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, 0, 0), inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

---

Thanks to **Parse Crash Report** I am able to get this :

```
Thread 0 (crashed)
0
CoreFoundation
__exceptionPreprocess @ 0x84
1
libobjc.A.dylib
objc_exception_throw @ 0x38
2
CoreFoundation
+[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] @ 0xd8
3
CoreFoundation
___forwarding___ @ 0x39c
4
CoreFoundation
_CF_forwarding_prep_0 @ 0x58
5
plizdoo
_TTSf4g_g___TFC7plizdoo23ToDoTableViewController13inviteFriendsfS0_FCSo8UIButtonT_ @ 0x35c
6
plizdoo
_TToFC7plizdoo23ToDoTableViewController13inviteFriendsfS0_FCSo8UIButtonT_ @ 0x24
7
UIKit
-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] @ 0x5c
8
UIKit
-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] @ 0x260
9
UIKit
-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] @ 0x24c
10
UIKit
_UIGestureRecognizerUpdate @ 0x2154
11
UIKit
-[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] @ 0x410
12
UIKit
-[UIWindow sendEvent:] @ 0x290
13
UIKit
-[UIApplication sendEvent:] @ 0x104
14
UIKit
_UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent @ 0x3c3c
15
UIKit
_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue @ 0x6b0
16
CoreFoundation
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ @ 0x14
17
CoreFoundation
__CFRunLoopDoSources0 @ 0x104
18
CoreFoundation
__CFRunLoopRun @ 0x2c4
19
CoreFoundation
CFRunLoopRunSpecific @ 0x188
20
GraphicsServices
GSEventRunModal @ 0xa4
21
UIKit
UIApplicationMain @ 0x5cc
22
plizdoo
main @ 0x98
23
libdyld.dylib
start @ 0x0
```

*If needed I can provide the complete crash report*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem was due to a swift compiler option.

**Here is how I solved it :**

1. Select project in Target
2. Build Settings
3. Swift Complier - Code Generation
4. Optimization Level
5. Set Debug and Release to : None [-Onone]